# How to add multiple data-content in jQuery popup?

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, popover

I want my popover to show multiple data-content, i.e. 3 different lines of text inside the popover. I have the following code, referred from w3schols.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div class="container">
  <h3>Popover Example</h3>
  <a href="#" data-toggle="popover" title="Popover Header" data-placement="bottom" data-content="Info 1">Toggle popover</a>
</div>

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('[data-toggle="popover"]').popover();   
});
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

The popover looks like this.

[Popover example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V1DaB.png)

I want the popover to show three more options like "Info 1", "Info 2" and "Info 3" like a list view. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

Try:

Demo;http://jsfiddle.net/jo6og612/

1)Define div with html which you want to show in popover

```
<div class="container">
   <h3>Popover Example</h3>
   <a href="#" data-toggle="popover" title="Popover Header" data-placement="bottom">Toggle popover</a>
   <div id="popover-content">
     <ul>
         <li> Info 1 </li>
         <li> Info 2 </li>
         <li> Info 3 </li>
     </ul>
   </div>   
</div>
```

2) Add content and html properties of popover

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('[data-toggle="popover"]').popover(
       html: true, 
       content: function() {
           return $('#popover-content').html();
       }
    );   
});
</script>
```